# Update remote database based on conditional statement

Tags: mysql, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pubnub

I have a MySQL database with a REST API for my main application hosted on Azure. I am setting up a hardware sensor with an additional database that will capture data multiple times a second. When a value changes by a specific threshold of the current value or after a specific time interval I want to make an API call to update the main database.

ie) Threshold is 10%. Last value was 10 this value is 12; this will set a trigger to call API and add to main database.

Can a trigger be added to the second database to make a HTTP request? Is there benefit to using another RDBMS in this case instead of MySQL? Does PubNub/Firebase make sense in this situation?

Comment: MYSQL databases dont have REST API's. I assume you have some software that is providing the REST API?

Comment: _When a value changes by a specific threshold of the current value or after a specific time interval I want to make an API call to update the main database._ This also needs to be coded in some sort of software!

Comment: PubNub has a KB article about this: https://support.pubnub.com/support/solutions/articles/14000043795-can-i-publish-a-message-via-a-database-trigger-